# What's the right move with SSL for user based site?

Tags: ssl

I'm working on a site where a user registers and has the ability to create various custom post types (let's call them tournaments for simplicity although it's slightly more complicated than just one CPT) that other site visitors can view.  The user has what amounts to some front end dashboard pages to manage their various tournaments.  They don't have access to the WP backend.  Users have account and profile pages in addition to that and everything else you would typically see on a membership style site.

I don't currently have SSL implemented but would like to.  I was playing around with it the other day on a test site and came across something I can't figure out the best way to handle.  I had planned on making all login/admin/account/dashboard pages served via HTTPS and keeping the "tournament" front end pages as well as blog articles and such served via HTTP.  However, when I do that and I am logged in (via HTTPS), and go to one of the tournament pages...it logs me out or at least shows me as logged out on that page.  This makes sense given that I'm logged into the HTTPS side, but I don't really know how I should handle this.  I have different menus for logged in vs not and I obviously don't want it to randomly log out users just because they go to a page I'm not forcing SSL on.  The vast majority of site visitors will not have accounts and I don't have a need now to secure all the pages outside of the aforementioned account pages.

My options as I see them:

1. Force SSL on the entire site without exception.  I don't think I have a particular problem with this, if this is the accepted practice now.  It sounds like there may be some pain down the road however with caching or CDN implementations.
2. Force SSL for any logged in user on every page they visit.  Non-logged in visitors would get http only.
3. Am I missing something else?  I want to force SSL only on the account and login pages but it wasn't a friendly experience the way it worked. It seems like this would a common scenario, hopefully I'm describing it well enough.  I've read every blog post out there on SSL for Wordpress and am aware of the simple one liners to force SSL on login and admin...and can make any htaccess changes and functions to do what I need.

thanks

Comment: I'd do for option 1. What are your concerns around caching and CDN?

Comment: Incomplete SSL is usually like installing a vault door to house. You can still get in through the windows..

Comment: What to you is incomplete SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either go site wide HTTPS, or should not bother with it in the first place. Should it be for all access or just for logged in users depends on the profile of your traffic. If most traffic will come from registered users, then just go unconditional HTTPS as doing it conditionaly just for logged in users obviously introduces more testing and might not play great with plugins that do not handle this situation well.

Side note: You should ask yourself why do it at all. Going HTTPS improves the general security against targeted attacks on specific users, but do not improve the general security of the site by much. It is more likely that a user's account will be broken into by brute force then by someone "listening" to his traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Mark.  If the majority of the traffic is from non-registered visitors, would you then side with SSL only for logged in users?

To your side note:  I understand what you're saying.  I think at this point it's just as much to gain any credibility from having it secure as much as anything.  With the new "Let's Encrypt" certificates, I figure why not if it is easy to do and doesn't cost anything.

Comment: @bassfan, my preferred option is SSL for logged in users. The thing about LetsEncrypt making things easier, it that it is only slightly true, it makes things mostly cheaperr, but most of the technical challenge is not with installing the certificate but to actually make sure that everything is served over HTTPS, which include images JS, CSS, fonts and what not, because if you have a mixed content situation then you do not provide any real security at all (which is why you get the warning signs in the browser). If you go to wordpress.com you probably see mixed content issues almost everywhere

Comment: mixed content - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content, can be more sever or less sever problem depends on what is mixed and how it interacts with the page. which bring back to the issue of why do you do it, if it is for privacy then mixed content is a real issue, but if just for protecting cookies it might be enough if you handle JS correctly. The thing is users are not likely to know the difference and will think your security is broken